Instalating and using keyboard lib python in the same script
I want to make a program than can run on any computer for the first time without making any command in cmd, using the keyboard lib.
I try this code:
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):

    def is_installed(command): #Check if installed
        return subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True).returncode == 0

    if is_installed(['python', '--version']): #Check if python installed
        if is_installed(['pip', '--version']): #Check if pip installed I run out in a case where python where install but not pip
            subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
            subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip','install', 'keyboard'])
        else:
            subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'get-pip.py'] ) 
            subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'] )
            subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip','install', 'keyboard'] )
    else: # If python not installed then download the installer and execute it
        subprocess.run(['curl', '-o', 'python-installer.exe', 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/python-3.12.0-amd64.exe'] )
        subprocess.run(['python-installer.exe', '/quiet', 'InstallAllUsers=1', 'PrependPath=1'] )
        subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'get-pip.py'] )
        subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
        subprocess.run(['cmd','/c', 'pip','install', 'keyboard'])

import keyboard

But I got an Error Module not found on the first execution after reinstalling python in vscode, then the second time I execute it it work with no problem and the lib work normaly.
